# A problem occurred configuring project ':app'. > Cannot run Project.afterEvaluate(Closure) when the project is already evaluated

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, gradle, sdk

What even is this lol. I am so confused as to what's going on, I just wanted to run my app, please. Im on VSCode, building for Android with Flutter.
Here is the error message.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 422

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Cannot run Project.afterEvaluate(Closure) when the project is already evaluated.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.`
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case OneSignal was the reason of the problem.

I change in my "android > gradle > wrapper > gradle-wrapper.properties" file the version of "distributionUrl" to "gradle-6.7.1-all.zip".

I guess is a problem with version 7 of gradle.

[image: gradle-wrapper.properties]